# Catching exceptions from a Jersey REST client thrown from a Spring MVC Rest service

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, exception, jersey

I implemented a REST application using Spring MVC, Jersey and JAXB.

The client sends a `ServiceRequest` object which contains information about the request and receives a `ServiceResponse` object back with information about the response.

ServiceRequest

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "servicerequest")
public class ServiceRequest{

    String serviceName = "AddUser"

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = name;
    }   
}
```

ServiceResponse

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "serviceresponse")
public class ServiceResponse {

    String responseCode; 

    public String getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setResponseCode(String code) {
        this.responseCode = name;
    }   
}
```

The client makes the call to the service using Jersey

ServiceClient

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource(RESOURCE_URL);

ServiceRequest request = new ServiceRequest();
ServiceResponse response = service.path("addUser").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).entity(request).post(ServiceRequest.class);
```

On the server side, the service gets the request, handles it and returns a `ServiceResponse` object.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            value = "/addUser",headers="Accept=application/xml")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)  
public @ResponseBody ServiceResponse addUser(@RequestBody ServiceRequest request) {

        ServiceResponse response = new ServiceResponse();

        //Handle request
        //service.addUser();

        response.setCode("200");
        return response; 
}
```

The controller class shown above makes a call to another service class to handle the request (`service.addUser()`). This service class can raise a number of exceptions.

What i am not sure of is how best to handle them. After *googling* around, i found that i can use an ExceptionHandler as shown below:

```
@ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
@ResponseBody
public String handleException1(NullPointerException ex)
{
    return ex.getMessage();
}
```

I can have the controllers extend a base class that has the exception handler.

A couple of questions regarding the above approach:

- Do i have to create one handler for each exception type? There are so many exceptions that i need to handle so is it not possible to just have a generic handler for all exceptions?
- As my controller returns an object of type `ServiceResponse`, what would be the object type that would be returned when an exception occurs?
- The client expects to get an object of `ServiceResponse` type. How does it work if the response is an exception type?

And finally, i noticed that the ExceptionHanlder can only have a return type that is one of the following:

```
ModelAndView
Model
Map
View
String – interpreted as a view name
void, but only if the method writes directly to the response object
```

I thought i can create the `ServiceResponse` object in the `ExceptionHandler` and set the appropriate code and return the `ServiceResponse` object. This however is not possible if i cant return a `ServiceResponse` type in the excpetion handler.

### Edit

I tried using the ExceptionHandler using a generic exception class as shown below

```
@ExceptionHandler(ServiceException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public @ResponseBody resolveServiceValidationException(ServiceException ex) {       

        System.out.println("In resolveServiceError");

        ServiceResponse = new ServiceResponse();
        response.setResponseException(ex.getMessage());
        return response;        
    }
```

The exception is being caught but the ServiceResponse object is always null. All i get is the following message:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/myService/services/pingError returned a response status of 400 Bad Request
```

How can i access the response object when an exception is returned back?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `@ExceptionHandler` annotation can take an array of classes as a parameter, so you can create only one (or more) handlers for multiple exceptions. Change the method signature to take the common ancestor of all handled exception classes as a parameter. Something along the lines:

   ```
   @ExceptionHandler(value = {NullPointerException.class, AnotherException.class})
   @ResponseBody
   public String handleException1(Exception ex) {
       return ex.getMessage();
   }
   ```
2. In your case it'll be `String`, since you annotated it with `@ResponseBody`, but you probably want to change the returned http code to some error code. You can do it by adding

   ```
   @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.WHATEVER_CODE_YOU_WANT, reason = "Your message")`
   ```

   annotation to your exception handler.
3. In case when http code returned by the call is greater or equal than `300`, jersey client throws `UniformInterfaceException`. You can catch and handle it. The response type doesn't matter in this case, as the exception is thrown before the conversion.

**update**

Once you get a hold of `UniformInterfaceException` and change the exception handler on the server so it returns `ServiceResponse` as response body, then you can get the reponse using:

```
ServiceResponse response = uniformInterfaceException.getResponse().getEntity(ServiceResponse.class);
```

Comment: I did try this but the response comes back as an error response meaning the ServiceResponse object is null. Is there a way i can read the ServiceResponse object? (See the edit in post)

Comment: @ziggy on spring side you can return it as a `@ResponseBody` of your exception handler. I'm not sure how to recover it on the jersey side.

Comment: @ziggy is `UniformInterfaceException` thrown in the client?

Comment: @ziggy your code for the client also isn't exaclty right, as `WebResource.post()` takes the class of the response as the parameter.